# Is it possible to style the dropdown of saved input field data

Tags: html, css, forms

I am styling a form with an input field. The input field is required to be completely transparent. The input field itself is no problem but once I start typing, the browser opens up the dropdown with the saved form data, displaying the words I previously entered in input fields. The dropdown itself is not transparent but is white. When I hover over one of the saved words it appears in the input field and when it does, the input field is also given the white background.

I tried setting the background for the active, focus and hover state to transparent but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I am also not able to see the saved form data dropdown in the element inspector so I don't know how to target it.

HTML:

```
<form class="" action="" method="_GET" accept-charset="utf-8" role="]">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="q">Search Input Field</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="SEARCH">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-red">SEARCH</button>
</form>
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtxeofnL/

Click into the input field and type a letter. If you have previously entered something in the input field (or another input field in your browser), the dropdown will appear. When you hover over one of the words in the dropdown, it'll appear in the input field and give it an opaque, white background.

Can this be done?

Comment: Can you set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ to see exactly where your at?

Comment: It sounds like this dropdown is coming from a browser plugin/extension. Regular <input> elements never have a dropdown component unless custom added.

Comment: @Alex, I think what he means is the `autocomplete` from the history

Comment: @Kyojimaru right I understand, but if I create a webpage with a single <input> element the page/element doesn't remember what I have typed in previously - if that is happening it is the browser / an extension that is remembering history on input fields per website. Basically this sounds like a per client (web browser) issue rather than an HTML,CSS,JS issue causing this dropdown to appear.

Comment: After visiting your jsfiddle, I cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: @Alex So the saved form data does not appear for you?

Comment: if you just want it so the autocomplete isn't shown/available add `autocomplete="off"` to the input other than that im not sure what you can do

Comment: @Parody It would have been nice to be able to style the autocomplete elements but this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete is browser and operating system specific. There doesn't appear to be any way to style the browser's own internal autocomplete function.

I would suggest disabling browser autocomplete altogether:

```
     <input autocomplete="off">
```

Then utilizing JqueryUI's Autocomplete function, http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/, which can be styled any which way you'd like.

Comment: I should add that Jquery Autocomplete will also allow you to predefine the autocomplete values you want your users to see.